# ParserError in reading csv using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Getting the following error in reading from a csv file of dimension 8 million * 20 (Using PC with 8GM RAM, and Anaconda 4)

Note, the same command works when run on:

1. A sample of the top 10000 records, using the same PC
2. The whole data, using a different PC with 16GM RAM, and Anaconda 3)

```
filename= "ec_all.csv"

df= pd.read_csv (filename,encoding= 'unicode_escape', low_memory=False, parse_dates=["FIRSTCLASS"])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-62582a9f3753> in <module>()
      1 # Reading data from file to create data frame
----> 2 df= pd.read_csv (filename,encoding= 'unicode_escape', low_memory=False, parse_dates=["FIRSTCLASS"])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    653                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    654 
--> 655         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    656 
    657     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    409 
    410     try:
--> 411         data = parser.read(nrows)
    412     finally:
    413         parser.close()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
    980                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
    981 
--> 982         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
    983 
    984         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1717     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1718         try:
-> 1719             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1720         except StopIteration:
   1721             if self._first_chunk:

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:10885)()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:12054)()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:28765)()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 2119608
```

Data snapshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a snap of your dataset which you are trying to load as a data frame i.e. the `ec_all.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the parameter `engine='python'`. This might get around the `EOF` issue.

Also you could add an `on_bad_lines` parameter to call a function for each problematic line. This could then be used to show the problematic line and code could then be added to possibly fix them (or just ignore them, depends how important the data is)

```py
import pandas as pd

def bad_line(x):
    print(x)
    return None

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', encoding='unicode_escape', on_bad_lines=bad_line, engine='python')

print(df)
```

The callable version of [`on_bad_lines`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) I think was added in version 1.3.0. You can check your version with:

```
print(pd.__version__)
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, but getting the following error now: ---->                                                6 df= pd.read_csv('ec_total.csv', encoding='unicode_escape', on_bad_lines=bad_line, engine='python')

TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_bad_lines'

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of pandas

Comment: Thanks, I tried. It appears that the issue gets resolved when run on a !6 GB machine